# ManagedQuery causing nullpointerexception

Tags: android, android-cursor, android-query

I am working on a project and want to read call logs and write them to file and send it to server. My code for reading call logs in working fine in a separate project. But it causes NullPointerException when integrates code with original project. All permissions are verified.
here is my code

```
BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true)); 
              buf.append("Testing ");
              buf.newLine();
                sb = new StringBuffer();
                Uri str = CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI;
                str.toString();
                Log.e("TAG", str.toString());


                  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            Cursor managedCursor =managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
                            null, null, null);
                Log.e("TAG", "in while " + ++i);
              int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
                int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
                int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
                int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
                sb.append("Call Details :");
```

Logcat shows this error
05-15 16:17:14.107: E/AndroidRuntime(20715): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 16:17:14.107: E/AndroidRuntime(20715): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.atu_proto/com.example.atu_proto.MenuList}: java.lang.NullPointerException

05-15 16:17:14.107: E/AndroidRuntime(20715):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2313)

05-15 16:17:14.107: E/AndroidRuntime(20715):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)

05-15 16:17:14.107: E/AndroidRuntime(20715):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)

05-15 16:17:14.107: E/AndroidRuntime(20715):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)

05-15 16:17:14.107: E/AndroidRuntime(20715):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

05-15 16:17:14.107: E/AndroidRuntime(20715):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)

05-15 16:17:14.107: E/AndroidRuntime(20715):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5336)

05-15 16:17:14.107: E/AndroidRuntime(20715):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

05-15 16:17:14.107: E/AndroidRuntime(20715):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

05-15 16:17:14.107: E/AndroidRuntime(20715):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)

05-15 16:17:14.107: E/AndroidRuntime(20715):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)

05-15 16:17:14.107: E/AndroidRuntime(20715):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

05-15 16:17:14.107: E/AndroidRuntime(20715): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

05-15 16:17:14.107: E/AndroidRuntime(20715):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getContentResolver(ContextWrapper.java:99)

05-15 16:17:14.107: E/AndroidRuntime(20715):    at android.app.Activity.managedQuery(Activity.java:1751)

05-15 16:17:14.107: E/AndroidRuntime(20715):    at com.example.atu_proto.CallLogsRetrieve.getCallDetails(CallLogsRetrieve.java:89)

05-15 16:17:14.107: E/AndroidRuntime(20715):    at com.example.atu_proto.MenuList.onCreate(MenuList.java:78)

05-15 16:17:14.107: E/AndroidRuntime(20715):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)

05-15 16:17:14.107: E/AndroidRuntime(20715):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)

05-15 16:17:14.107: E/AndroidRuntime(20715):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2277)
05-15 16:17:14.107: E/AndroidRuntime(20715):    ... 11 more

Comment: can u attach logcat please

Comment: If you get exceptions always include the logcat in your question.

Comment: I have attached logcat output. Please check this.

Comment: Post your `onCreate()` where you call `getCallDetails()`

Comment: I am making my call to CallLogsRetrieve Activity in this way.
CallLogsRetrieve clr = new CallLogsRetrieve();
String path = clr.getCallDetails();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 05-15 16:17:14.107: E/AndroidRuntime(20715): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> 05-15 16:17:14.107: E/AndroidRuntime(20715): at android.content.ContextWrapper.getContentResolver(ContextWrapper.java:99)
>
> ...
>
> 05-15 16:17:14.107: E/AndroidRuntime(20715): at com.example.atu_proto.CallLogsRetrieve.getCallDetails(CallLogsRetrieve.java:89)
>
> 05-15 16:17:14.107: E/AndroidRuntime(20715): at com.example.atu_proto.MenuList.onCreate(MenuList.java:78)

This suggests you're calling another activity from your `MenuList` activity, likely creating the other activity with `new`.

Never instantiate activities with `new`.

In this case it seems `CallLogsRetrieve` should not be an activity and you could pass in an `Activity` reference as an argument to methods that need it.

Comment: Thanx alot... laalto.. :) :) :)
your guidance did my work. :)
i removed activity and passed refrence of previous activity and job done for my :)
thanx alot :)